# Eliminar registros con ajax rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando eliminar registros de mi tabla, sin embargo aunque los elimina no actualiza la lista con ajax:

**enterprises_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
    @enterprise_tag.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enterprise_tag.destroy
        format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: "enterprise was remove successfully" }
        format.js { render partial: "list" }
      end
    end

end
```

**destroy.js.erb** **[ ¿Falta algo qui? ]**

```
<% if @enterprise_tag.errors.empty? %>
  $("#items").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list') %>");
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise_tags.any? %>
  <table id="items">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Fecha de creacion</td>
        <td colspan="2">Opciones</td>
      </tr>
      <% @enterprise_tags.each do |enterprise_tag| %>
        <%= render partial: "enterprise_tags/list", locals: { enterprise_tag:enterprise_tag } %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% else %>
    <div class="callout small text-center">
      <span>No hay ningun registro disponible</span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**_list.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to enterprise_tag_path(enterprise_tag), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "¿Desea eliminar este registro?" }, remote: true do %><i class="fi-trash"></i><% end %></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este código

```
<% if @enterprise_tag.errors.empty? %>
  $("#items").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list') %>");
<% end %>
```

en realidad no estás borrando nada, de hecho `append` te sirve para agregar html a tus elementos, no para borrar.
Una solución podría ser agregarles id a los tags `tr` de tu lista:

```
<tr id='enterprise-tag-<%= enterprise_tag.id %>'>
  <td><%= link_to enterprise_tag_path(enterprise_tag), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "¿Desea eliminar este registro?" }, remote: true do %><i class="fi-trash"></i><% end %></td>
</tr>
```

luego en tu `destroy.js.erb`, podrías borrar el tag específico basado en su id:

```
<% if @enterprise_tag.errors.empty? %>
  $("#enterprise-tag-<%= @enterprise_tag.id %>").remove();
<% end %>
```

Comment: Va perfecto Alter! Te agradezco muchisimo! 

Como ultima instancia Alter, sabes en que podria modificar aqui para este caso de mi update:

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41933/problemas-al-actualizar-un-registro-con-ajax-rails

Comment: @HectorHernandez si la respuesta te fue de utilidad, recuerda que puedes marcarla como aceptada. Voy a echarle una mirada a tu otra pregunta. Saludos