# Problemas al actualizar un registro con Ajax Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Me sucede un pequeño problema, mas que problema una mala experiencia de navegación, cuando actualizo el registro por medio de Ajax, el registro original se mantiene, y el actualizado se queda como agregado, cuando debería actualizar la misma celda, hasta que actualizo la pagina el registro antiguo desaparece, para una mejor comprensión lo explico en 2 imágenes:

En esta imagen acabo de editar un archivo, la tabla mantiene el registro original, aunque de forma temporal mientras la pagina no se recargue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la pagina se recarga, el registro original desaparece y el editado queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo ha de ser la forma en como actualizo el archivo, a continuación comparto mi código, espero puedan ayudarme:

**update.js.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise_tag.errors.empty? %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
  $("enterprise-<%= @enterprise.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list', locals: { enterprise:@enterprise }) %>");
<% end %>
```

**enterprise_tags_controller.rb**

```
  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enterprise_tag.update(enterprise_tag_params)
        format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: 'enterprise_tag was successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @enterprise_tag, status: :created, location: @enterprise_tag }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @enterprise_tag.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**link_edit**

```
<%= link_to edit_enterprise_tag_path(enterprise_tag), remote: true, :data => { :open => 'exampleModal1' }, class: "button tiny green" do %><i class="fi-pencil"></i><% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<table id="enterprise-tags-items">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Fecha de creacion</td>
                <td colspan="2">Opciones</td>
              </tr>
              <% @enterprise_tags.each do |enterprise_tag| %>
                <%= render partial: "enterprise_tags/list", locals: { enterprise_tag:enterprise_tag } %>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion al problema:

$("#enterprise-<%= @enterprise.id %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list', locals: { enterprise:@enterprise }) %>");

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que insistes en usar `append` y, como te comentaba [en la respuesta de tu problema anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/41986/213), esa función es para insertar contenido, no para reemplazar ni para borrar.
Te sugiero que revises [la documentación de Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/append/) cuando no tengas claro que es lo que hace específicamente una función. Lo que deberías usar es la función [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) e implementar el reemplazo de manera similar a la respuesta que te di en tu otro problema.

Comment: He actualizado el archivo cambie el .append a .html y cambie el id, pero no me actualiza la tabla, incluso usando el antiguo id que engloba la tabla: "enterprises-items", no se si tengo q agregar algo parecido a la respuesta anterior que me distes .update()

Comment: Logre solucionarlo Alter de esta manera:

$("#enterprise-<%= @enterprise.id %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list', locals: { enterprise:@enterprise }) %>");

Saludos!